# C# XAML dynamic binding to Database during database operation

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my code behind I have bound my ListBox's ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection and I am able to retrieve and view all the items as desired.

The problem comes in when I try to add a new item to the database. The view doesnt get updated until unless I explicitly set the ItemsSource again which makes sense since when the data was bound, it was bound to the old data set in the database.

Is there a way I can avoid setting the ItemsSource explicitly or adding an item to the list explicitly?

I am trying to achieve this just by a mere insert into the database!

```
Code:

//Declarations

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public ObservableCollection<DBList> itemList = new ObservableCollection<DBList>(dbConn.Table<DBList>().ToList().Where(c1 => c1.ID != null && !c1.value));
public ObservableCollection<DBList> ItemList
{
    get{return this.itemList;}
    set{this.itemList = value;}
}

//Constructor
DBListBox.ItemsSource = ItemList;

//Method in which I add item to database
private void AddToList(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{           
     InsertToDatabase("abc","xyz"); //Code Inserts a new item in database

     //Method 1: The view is updated in this case when I add item to the List
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
     {
          ItemList.Add(new DBList() { Id="abc" , value="xyz"});
          NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemList");
     });

     //Method 2: The view is updated in this case when I explicitly set the ItemsSouce to a fresh list from the Database
     DBListBox.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<DBList>(dbConn.Table<DBList>().ToList().Where(c1 => c1.ID != null && !c1.value));
}

private void InsertToDatabase(string id, string value)
{
       dbConn.CreateTable<DBList>();
       DBList cTemp = new DBList(){Id = id, value = value};                
       dbConn.InsertOrReplace(cTemp);           
}
```

Comment: Are you using the wrong NotifyPropertyChanged? Shouldn't call **ItemList** instead of ChatList?

Comment: @Smartis I'm sorry it was a typo. It is indeed ItemList that is being called. The two methods above work fine. I am trying a way in which I can avoid doing this. Just an insert into the table must update the view

Comment: Can you share the code of `InsertToDatabase`?

Comment: @DanPuzey Edited the Question with the `InsertToDatabase` Code